# How to limit content with html tags in a DIV

Tags: php, javascript, html, text, editor

I have a text editor in my website and my customer's job is: "Text Pasting From Microsoft Office".
And Microsoft Office embed many tags in background and this tags destroy my page view.

I can't use BBCode and I can't limit users.

How I can limit this tags just in a DIV that when html tags crashed, my page view does not destroy?

How I keep page style without attention to pasted text form Microsoft office?
What  do you recommend?

Comment: I see PHP tagged in your question - can you use strip_tags?

Comment: Why dont you try `CSS's` overflow property if you want to limit it to a certain amount of size?

Comment: @Floris no dude, I can't :\ they need to bold text or colored text or ...

Answer (score 1):

you can use ckeditor that support cut,copy and paste from word document to text editor.

this is manual
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Document/Cut,_Copy_and_Paste